# Unable to run bigtable emulator for testing grpc-java code

Tags: grpc-java, google-cloud-bigtable

I am writing a service where data will be stored on bigtable. I want to use bigtable emulator run the test. In setup when trying to start the emulator I get following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.iam.v1.TestIamPermissionsRequest tried to access method 'com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.emptyList()' (com.google.iam.v1.TestIamPermissionsRequest and com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.google.iam.v1.TestIamPermissionsRequest.<init>(TestIamPermissionsRequest.java:127)
    at com.google.iam.v1.TestIamPermissionsRequest.<clinit>(TestIamPermissionsRequest.java:918)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.stub.GrpcBigtableTableAdminStub.<clinit>(GrpcBigtableTableAdminStub.java:314)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.BigtableTableAdminClient.create(BigtableTableAdminClient.java:150)
    at com.ce.table.UserTableTest.setUp(UserTableTest.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at com.google.testing.junit.runner.internal.junit4.CancellableRequestFactory$CancellableRunner.run(CancellableRequestFactory.java:108)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at com.google.testing.junit.runner.junit4.JUnit4Runner.run(JUnit4Runner.java:116)
    at com.google.testing.junit.runner.BazelTestRunner.runTestsInSuite(BazelTestRunner.java:145)
    at com.google.testing.junit.runner.BazelTestRunner.main(BazelTestRunner.java:76)
```

I have tried to different combination of the versions of bigtable and io_grpc library.
But I am not able to make any progress. I am not sure which version combination should work here.

Attaching my WORKSPACE, BUILD and Java test file for reference.

Java code:

```
package com.ce.table;

import com.ce.proto.v1.User;
import com.ce.util.Util;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.BigtableTableAdminClient;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.BigtableTableAdminSettings;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.models.CreateTableRequest;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.admin.v2.models.GCRules;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataSettings;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.emulator.v2.BigtableEmulatorRule;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UserTableTest {

    @Rule
    public final BigtableEmulatorRule bigtableEmulator = BigtableEmulatorRule.create();
    private final String orgId = "test-org";
    private final String projectId = "test-project";
    private final String instanceId = "test-instance";
    private Table userTable;
    private BigtableDataClient dataClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        BigtableTableAdminSettings.Builder tableAdminSettings = BigtableTableAdminSettings.newBuilderForEmulator(
                bigtableEmulator.getPort()).setProjectId(projectId).setInstanceId(instanceId);
        BigtableTableAdminClient tableAdminClient = BigtableTableAdminClient.create(
                tableAdminSettings.build());

        tableAdminClient.createTable(CreateTableRequest.of(UserTable.TABLE_ID)
                .addFamily(UserTable.COLUMN_FAMILY, GCRules.GCRULES.maxVersions(1)));
        // Create Bigtable data client
        BigtableDataSettings.Builder dataSettings = BigtableDataSettings.newBuilderForEmulator(
                bigtableEmulator.getPort()).setProjectId(projectId).setInstanceId(instanceId);
        dataClient = BigtableDataClient.create(dataSettings.build());

        userTable = new UserTable(dataClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("device", "android");
        data.put("name", "test-user");
        User user = User.newBuilder()
                .setOrganizationId(orgId)
                .setProjectId(projectId)
                .setId("test-user-save")
                .putAllData(data)
                .build();

        boolean savedUser = userTable.save(user);
        assertEquals(true, savedUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        String userId = "test-user-get";
        String deviceKey = "device";
        String deviceValue = "android";
        String nameKey = "name";
        String nameValue = "test-user";
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(deviceKey, deviceValue);
        data.put(nameKey, nameValue);
        User user = User.newBuilder()
                .setOrganizationId(orgId)
                .setProjectId(projectId)
                .setId(userId)
                .putAllData(data)
                .build();

        boolean savedUser = userTable.save(user);
        assertEquals(true, savedUser);

        Optional<User> getUserOpt = userTable.get(Util.createRowKey(orgId, projectId, userId));

        User getUser = getUserOpt.get();

        assertEquals(orgId, getUser.getOrganizationId());
        assertEquals(projectId, getUser.getProjectId());
        assertEquals(userId, getUser.getId());

        Map<String, String> getUserDataMap = getUser.getDataMap();
        assertEquals(getUserDataMap.get(deviceKey), data.get(deviceKey));
        assertEquals(getUserDataMap.get(nameKey), data.get(nameKey));

    }
}
```

My WORKSPACE file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto_grpc",
    sha256 = "9ba7299c5eb6ec45b6b9a0ceb9916d0ab96789ac8218269322f0124c0c0d24e2",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto_grpc-4.5.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/rules-proto-grpc/rules_proto_grpc/releases/download/4.5.0/rules_proto_grpc-4.5.0.tar.gz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "com_google_googleapis",
    sha256 = "0744d1a1834ab350126b12ebe2b4bb1c8feb5883bd1ba0a6e876cb741d569994",
    strip_prefix = "googleapis-bcc476396e799806d3355e87246c6becf6250a70",
    urls = ["https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/archive/bcc476396e799806d3355e87246c6becf6250a70.tar.gz"],
)

load("@com_google_googleapis//:repository_rules.bzl", "switched_rules_by_language")
switched_rules_by_language(
    name = "com_google_googleapis_imports",
    java = True,
    grpc = True,
)

load("@rules_proto_grpc//:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_grpc_toolchains", "rules_proto_grpc_repos")
rules_proto_grpc_toolchains()
rules_proto_grpc_repos()

load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()
load("@rules_proto_grpc//java:repositories.bzl", rules_proto_grpc_java_repos = "java_repos")

rules_proto_grpc_java_repos()

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")
load("@io_grpc_grpc_java//:repositories.bzl", "IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_ARTIFACTS", "IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_OVERRIDE_TARGETS", "grpc_java_repositories")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.15.0.RELEASE",
        "io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.59.0",
        "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigtable:2.29.1",
        "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigtable-emulator:0.160.1",
    ] + IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_ARTIFACTS,
    generate_compat_repositories = True,
    # override_targets = IO_GRPC_GRPC_JAVA_OVERRIDE_TARGETS,
    fetch_sources = True,
    repositories = [
        "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
    ],
)

load("@maven//:compat.bzl", "compat_repositories")

compat_repositories()

grpc_java_repositories()
```

BUILD File:

```
java_binary(
    name = "datastore",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/**/*.java"]),
    main_class = "com.ce.Server",
    resources = ["src/main/resources/application.properties"],
    deps = [
        "//protos/v1:java_lib_protos",
        "//protos/v1:service_java_grpc",
        "@maven//:com_google_auth_google_auth_library_oauth2_http",
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_google_cloud_bigtable",
        "@maven//:com_google_protobuf_protobuf_java",
        "@maven//:io_grpc_grpc_core",
        "@maven//:net_devh_grpc_server_spring_boot_autoconfigure",
        "@maven//:net_devh_grpc_server_spring_boot_starter",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_autoconfigure",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_spring_beans",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_spring_context",
    ],
)

java_test(
    name = "all_tests",
    size = "small",
    srcs = glob(["src/test/**/*.java"]),
    test_class = "com.ce.AllTest",
    deps = [
        ":datastore",
        "//protos/v1:java_lib_protos",
        "//protos/v1:service_java_grpc",
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_google_cloud_bigtable",
        "@maven//:com_google_cloud_google_cloud_bigtable_emulator",
        "@maven//:junit_junit",
    ],
)
```

Comment: May I know which guide you are following? Have you tried this [Github link](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/tree/main/google-cloud-bigtable-emulator)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 

I got the dependency from some medium blog. 

[The dependencies are too old and breaking other changes](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/tree/main/google-cloud-bigtable-emulator)

Comment: Please post this as your answer if you already resolved the issue so that it could be helpful to other community members.